# Proper syntax for updating a row in Android with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax

Ok, I have two Android projects both running the same API level. In one, to update a SQLite row I am using:

```
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null);
```

In the other I am using:

```
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, updateValues, FIELD_COLLECTION_ID + "=?", new String[] {collectionId});
```

They both work. Except that in the second project, if I change the syntax to match the first one, (i.e. remove the question mark from the where clause and set `whereArgs` to null), it returns 0 rows affected. Is there a reason for this? Im thinking of sticking to the second syntax because apparently it reduces the possibility of SQL injection but I thought I would throw this one out there and see if anyone had a similar experience.

Also interesting is that the documentation doesn't specify what whereArgs is for, its just there: [SQLiteDatabase:update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove the question mark, are you replacing it with the value of `collectionId`?

The second syntax means that SQLite can reuse the same cached copy of the query for any number of different values of `rowId` or `collectionId`, rather than having a completely different query each time it's invoked. Saves lots of resources.